# How can copy a treenode (with children) in react sortable tree and paste elsewhere in the tree?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, contextmenu

I am using React-sortable-tree for drag and drop functionality, I want to copy and paste between the tree. How can I achieve this?

I was trying to add a context menu for right-click

I have done so much R&D still not found an accurate result